# Unable to access internet from subnet created by DD-WRT repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have flashed a Lynksys WRT54GS v6 with DD-WRT v24-SP2. I have been successful in running the router as a repeater-bridge, however this does not encompass the functionality I want.

The repeater-bridge configuration uses the primary router to create the IP tables. I would like the secondary router on a separate subnet to abstract my servers from the larger network.

After a hard reset, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater#Broadcom_Considerations).

I have checked and rechecked that my settings are correct. I can connect to the secondary router and configure it both wirelessly and wired, however the clients of the second router are unable to connect to the internet.

If I connect to the primary router, I am able to access the internet.

I noticed that the `gateway` and `Local DNS` settings are both at `0.0.0.0`. Perhaps this has something to do with it?

How do I troubleshoot my connection?

Comment: on what device is the dns/gateway 0.0.0.0? if its the clients, then yes, that is definitely a problem. do you have a DNS server? if not, find out what a working terminal is using and statically configure that on your device, or subnet's dhcp server.

Comment: @Frank Thomas, I'm kind of a newbie to this kind of thing. By "working terminal" what do you mean? Will a computer connected to the primary router have a suitible gateway and Local DNS for clients of the subnet?

Comment: Your gateway should be pointing at the IP address of the router that is being used to connect to the internet (the first router).   I would try to set the local DNS to IP of the first router.   If that does not work, try a public DNS server such as 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.3-7 to see if that works or not.   Local DNS is not necessarily needed to resolve machines locally, but will be needed for sure out on the public internet if you plan on doing anything at all.

Comment: @Richie086 I just switched the local DNS and gateway...still nothing. My primary router's local IP is 192.168.1.1. I have set the secondary router's (repeater's) local IP to 192.168.2.1. The primary and secondary routers' subnet masks are set to 255.255.255.0. The secondary router's gateway is set to 192.168.1.1. Using this configuration I have tried setting the Local DNS of the secondary router to 192.168.1.1 and 8.8.8.8. Still no internet connection.

Comment: If you can ping 192.168.1.1 but no 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.2.1, you have to add a route in 192.168.2.1 to 0.0.0.0 through gateway 192.168.1.1, because maybe the only route you have is to 192.168.1.0 and traffic doesn't know how to get outside.

Comment: Ahh! There's the problem! I can't ping 192.168.1.1 because I'm not connected to the primary router. I tried to go into client mode, client-bridge mode, repeater-bridge mode, and repeater mode. I could not get connected to the router at all. However, it was working yesterday! I have confirmed that my SSID, passkey, encryption type, and interface type are correct.

Comment: Okay, judging from the guide you posted: Does the repeater get a 192.168.1.x address from your main router, or did you manually configure such a static ip address? What happens to devices connected to the repeater - do they get an ip address by DHCP and if yes, in which range is that ip address?

Comment: No. The router is in a different subnet. The repeater has DHCP clients.